# Me aparece un error que dice que no coinciden los tipos

Tags: vba

El error esta Justo en el comentario que dice BUSQUEDA POR NOMBRE DEL DIRECTOR. Temo que vaya a generar el mismo para todo el código, ya que todo ha sido copiado y pegado multiples veces; sé que se puede optimizar de muchas formas, pero mi interés en este momento es quitar el error. Les agradezco mucho.

```
Private Sub Buscar_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

items = Range("A2:L400").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To items

    'BUSQUEDA POR NOMBRE DEL DIRECTOR
    ElseIf LCase(Cells(i, 7).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.Palabra_Text.Value) & "*" Then
    Me.Lista_Cd.AddItem Cells(i, 1)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(i, 3)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(i, 4)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cells(i, 5)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cells(i, 6)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 6) = Cells(i, 7)

   'Busqueda por año
    ElseIf LCase(Cells(i, 11).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.Palabra_Text.Value) & "*" Then
    Me.Lista_Cd.AddItem Cells(i, 1)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(i, 3)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(i, 4)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cells(i, 5)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cells(i, 6)
    Me.Lista_Cd.List(Me.Lista_Cd.ListCount - 1, 6) = Cells(i, 7)


    End If

    Next i
    Me.Palabra_Text.SetFocus
    Me.Palabra_Text.SelStart = 0
    Me.Palabra_Text.SelLength = Len(Me.Palabra_Text.Text)

    Exit Sub



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Estas comenzando el bloque con un `ElseIf`. ¿No debería ser `If LCase(Cells(i, 7).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.Palabra_Text.Value) & "*" Then`?

Comment: Que pena, pero es que tuve que borrar parte del código

Comment: En qué línea te sale marcado el error?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar

```
ElseIf LCase(Cells(i, 7).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.Palabra_Text.Value) & "*" Then
```

Por

```
If LCase(Cells(i, 7).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.Palabra_Text.Value) & "*" Then
```